# All Javascript line not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html page is as-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 var s = $("#d").get(0).getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(var x=0;x<s.length;x++){
    document.writeln(s.length);
  }
  var k=document.createElement("a");
  k.innerHTML="hello";
  var q=document.getElementById("d");
  q.appendChild(k);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d">
<a><img class="zzz"/></a>
<a><img class="zzz"/></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript executes only up to **for** loop (element k is not appended). If **for** loop is removed then only **element k** got appended. Isn't code below for loop is supposed to be executed after for loop execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! A few suggestions to help you as you are learning to develop:

- Always use meaningful variable names, it's hard to keep track of what
  single letter variables represent
- Don't use document.write for
  debugging, use the console for that
- If you are using a library like
  jQuery, try to use it as much as you can when you are beginning to
  learn it. Only fall back to basic javascript if you have a compelling
  reason to do so

Your function can be rewritten in pure jQuery like so:

```
$(function() {
  var container = $('#d');
  console.log(container.find('a').length);
  container.append('<a>hello</a>');
});
```

I haven't run your code, but your error probably has to do with this statement: `$("#d").get(0).getElementsByTagName("a");`. The [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method returns a jQuery object, which does not have a `getElementsByTagName()` method on it.

If you want a plain DOM object without the jQuery wrapper you can address the jQuery object like an array: `$('#d')[0].getElementsByTagName("a");`, though like I said, it's best to stick with the jQuery library if you are going to use it.

Good luck as you learn!

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `writeln` (or `write`) after the document has been loaded(or I better say: you shouldn't, because it will overwrite the complete document, including `#d` , what will force the error, because this element isn't available anymore after the usage of `writeln` )

I guess you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('a').prepend(function(i){return i;});
  $('#d').append('hello');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/stRBU/2/